# WP8 Binding DependencyProperty of a custom Button to another DependencyProperty of a UserControl not work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8

Let's say I have two UserControl: `uc1` and `uc2`.  `uc1` is derived from `Button`, `uc2` is derived from `UserControl`.

`uc1` has a `DependencyProperty` `isTextShow`:

C#:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty isTextShowProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "isTextShow", 
    typeof(bool), 
    typeof(uc1),
    new PropertyMetadata(true));

public bool isTextShow
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(isTextShowProperty ); }
    set { SetValue(isTextShowProperty , value); } 
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button x:Class="xx.xx.uc1"
    ....
    x:Name="ButtonBase">

    <TextBlock 
        ..
        Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ButtonBase, Path=isTextShow, Converter="{StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}"}">
    </TextBlock>
    ....     
</Button>
```

---

`uc2` has a `DependencyProperty` `isWhatEver`:

C#:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty isWhatEverProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "isWhatEver", 
    typeof(bool), 
    typeof(uc2),
    new PropertyMetadata(true));

public bool isWhatEver
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(isWhatEverProperty ); }
    set { SetValue(isWhatEverProperty , value); } 
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xx.xx.uc2"
    ....
    x:Name="UCBase">

    <uc1
        ..
        isTextShow="{Binding ElementName=UCBase, Path=isWhatEver}">
    </uc1>
    ....
```

Now I use `uc2` in some places like below:

```
<uc2 
    ....
    isWhatEver="False"
/>
```

I predicted that after this, the `TextBlock` in `uc1` would not show, but the result is it is still visible.
I made breakpoint in some essential places and found that the `isWhatEver` became False, but the `isTextShow` of `uc1` bound to it was still True.  It seems something wrong with this Binding.

Further more, I changed this line:

```
isTextShow="{Binding ElementName=UCBase, Path=isWhatEver}"
```

to

```
isTextShow="False",
```

This time, the `TextBlock` in `uc1` didn't show up.  So it means the first layer binding works fine, but the second layer(Binding DependencyProperty of UserControl one to another DependencyProperty of UserControl two) doesn't work.

Is there anything important I ignored?  Thank you.

---

Update:
I think now I know the reason, but I still don't know the solution.
The reason is: `uc1` is derived from `Button`; if I change `uc1` to be derived from `UserControl`, it works fine!  But for current situation, I really need make `uc1` as a child of `Button`, so any ideas?

Comment: If you wish to bind a DP to itself (Button-IsTextShow) you must either set the DataContext to be itself, or from using a UserControl style to a Custom Control Style and use TemplateBinding to the property

Comment: Hi @ShawnKendrot Thank you for your response.  I use `Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ButtonBase, Path=isTextShow, Converter="{StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}"}"` to indicate the ElementName already, is it the equivalent as set DataContext to itself?  Could you give some more detailed information.  Thx.

Comment: Ah, sorry, did not see ElementName. Do you have many of these on a page?

Comment: The code above is just a demo.  I have several DP should be bound in this way.

Comment: Hi @ShawnKendrot see above I have updated my question.  Do you have any ideas about this?  Thank you.